# Revert to system installed version ruby 1.8.7

Tags: rvm

I installed ruby 1.9.3 using RVM. I want to use 1.8.7 interpreter whenever I open a new terminal session. Currently I have to type `rvm system` every time I open the terminal.

Comment: Upgraded your system Ruby install or installed 1.9.3 using RVM? They are two very different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote [RVM's documentatio](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/default/)n:

> If you wish to switch back to your system ruby as default, remember
>   that RVM does not "manage" the system ruby and is "hands off".
>
> This means to set the "system" ruby as default, you reset RVM's
>   defaults as follows:
>
> ```
> rvm reset
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I not sure about reverting back.. But you can use .rvmrc file to avoid keep on typing `rvm system` command. Create a file in the name of `.rvmrc` and store the command `rvm system` in it. Move the file to specific path.. In your case in home/root folder. Now by default. It will use system ruby. check the below link for more details
[rvmrc](http://beginrescueend.com/workflow/rvmrc/)